# Do I need to apply for Portuguese residency visa in UK or Portugal when married to Portuguese citizen?

Tags: eu-spouses, residence-cards, portugal

I am planning to move with my husband from the UK to Portugal, I am a UK citizen and my husband of 11 years is Portuguese and we have 2 children with duel citizenship.

Do I need to apply for a visa before going to Portugal or can I apply for residency once there?

I am only allowed 3 months in Portugal now the UK is no longer in the EU, so my worry is if my residency isn't sorted in that time would I have issues leaving and returning to Portugal?

Comment: I'd suggest checking it with the Portuguese embassy in England beforehand (they may have information posted on their web page or you could email/call them). I can't say anything definite about UK-Portugal, but some European countries require obtaining spouse visa before entering, and then converting it to residence card - this depends on the country of destination and your nationality.

Answer (score 1):

After your arrival in Portugal, you must apply for a **residence card** as a spouse of a EU Citizen. A certificate should be issued immediately.

- [Registration certificate for EU citizens or members of their families who do not have European nationality](https://eportugal.gov.pt/en/cidadaos-europeus-viajar-viver-e-fazer-negocios-em-portugal/viver-em-portugal/residir-em-portugal#maistresmesescartao)

As an UK citizen, you do not require a visa beforhand.

Comment: Many thanks Mark, this is really useful. I was just worried about the part that says you apply after 3 months of being there, if I am only allowed to stay 90 days. But good to know the residence card should be issued immediately.

Comment: @KatieGomes This should be understood has: if you are planing to stay longer than 3 months, then you must register - at the lastest - after 3 months. Nothing prevents you from doing this earlier.

Comment: @KatieGomes the 90-day limit that applies to most citizens of the UK does not apply to family members of EU citizens when they're with their EU-citizen family member.

Comment: @phoog Yes, but the 3 months still applies to non-Portugese EU Citizens and family members.

Comment: @MarkJohnson but the consequences for exceeding the three months without applying for a residence card should be minor -- a fine or similar.  Someone who _is_ subject to the normal 90-day limit for third-country nationals can be expelled as punishment for exceeding it; this can't happen to an EU citizen or family member.